# Where is data on stable currents of world ocean?

Tags: data-request

I wonder where can we find data on stable currents of world ocean (with respect to the fact that ap same 2d point on map can exist diferent currents that have different altitude)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am by no means a subject matter expert on the type of data you are looking for but am good at finding open data :)

Have you tried http://www.oscar.noaa.gov/datadisplay/oscar_datadownload.php?pagetype=nonjava by any chance? Data comes down as a NetCDF file but there are file readers for different operating systems (I used Panoply for Mac) and then you can export to CDL which could be parsed by any number of programming languages.

NOAA has other ocean current data sets and information at http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/General/current.html too

Is this on the right track for the data you're looking for?

Comment: Just for fun, I thought I'd add this link to an animated map of world ocean currents made with that Oscar data: http://earth.nullschool.net/#current/ocean/surface/currents/orthographic

Answer (score 4):

Databasin.org has this you have to register an account to download but its open and free to do so. http://databasin.org/datasets/d707c80bc307475cb7b465ee92520c12

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend ERDDAP https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/index.html for marine data products and HYCOM for modeled data https://www.hycom.org/